# Do I need a tourist permit to return to Mexico by air?

Tags: visas, mexico, tourist-visas

I recently became a US citizen and I want to travel back to México for a couple of days. According to the mexican constitution i can have dual nationality  so do I need a permit to enter back by air? I still have a mexican ID that hasn't expired but only have  an amerocan passport that also states my country of birth.

Comment: Are you a Mexican citizen? What did you need to enter Mexico before you became a US citizen?

Comment: I used my permanent resident card.. but I've always traveled by air. And last time i entered as a US citizen they didn't asked for a permit or anything like that. This will be my first time by air and I want  to know if I need a Tourist permit or something similar.

Comment: Please clarify if you're a Mexican citizen or not. What is this "Mexican ID" that you have?

Comment: Yes, I have dual citizennship. And the mexican id it's called a "credential to vote" issued by INE a government institution that regulates electoral processes, and works just as the US ID. And I also have my birth certificate.